# Hibernate with Domain Model, but no client

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I have a complex Domain Model that interacts with hardware.  There is effectively no human UI or interaction with other systems other than the hardware.

The Domain Model operates the hardware continuously, adjusting aspects of it so it operates efficiently.

I want to store some key decisions the Domain Model is making in a database with Hibernate.  How do I have the Domain Model do this given that there is no "application layer".  Am I forced to add some knowledge of Hibernate into the Domain Model?  Is it OK that the Domain Model directly interact with Hibernate in this case?

Comment: Where do your inputs come from ? Are there identified "use cases" or domain tasks performed by someone or something ? At what point do you load stuff from the database ?

Comment: No, this is a true object-oriented rich domain model application.  "Use cases" are not used to define the functionality of the system.  The domain model as I mentioned makes decisions itself.  They are not made by humans.  Are you saying there must be?

Comment: Not necessarily. The Application Layer simply takes inputs and orchestrates calls to domain model objects based on these inputs. At the end of the process, it saves the objects back to the DB. A more detailed description of your problem might help telling if your system falls under that model or not.

Comment: @guillaume - many thanks.  I guess your saying I should consider introducing an application layer.  However, the application has worked well for years, and I just wanted to save some data to a database without re-architecting it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you do have an application component, and it is sitting between the hardware and your domain model.

You can probably figure out where the seams are by considering how to write automated tests for different scenarios.  That is to say, if you are going to simulate the hardware, which bits do you keep, and which do you stub out/replace?

You'd probably want to write a test that looks something like

```
Given (these previous observations)
When (this observation happens)
Then (the domain model decides the right thing)
```

The "other stuff" (actually listening to the hardware, actually sending commands to the controller) is probably in the application component.  That's where I would expect the interface with Hibernate to be.

Comment: Are you saying software *must* have an application "layer"?  There isn't one.  One could write tests by mocking the hardware.  But this was a question about saving decisions made by the intelligent domain model to a database?